# DataGridView - don't allow the user to add new row if the previous one contain empty cells?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview on my form and I want to allow user to add new row only if he fills up all cells in the previous one.

How I can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new row to datagridview only after specific cells of the row above are filled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126523/how-to-add-new-row-to-datagridview-only-after-specific-cells-of-the-row-above-are)

Comment: @Cody Gray: the code is not working as I need

Comment: That's not very helpful. I can't very well tell you how to fix something if you don't tell me what's wrong with it. You really need to put more effort into your questions than this.

Comment: @Cody Gray: What I want is to check every cell in the row and if there is one empty, display a message for the user for example to tell him to fill the empty cells and all this will happen when the user try to insert new row in the datagridview

Comment: Yup, the answer to that question is how to do that. You'll have to do some thinking on your own. For example, it doesn't already have the code written to show a message box. But your question isn't nearly detailed enough for anyone answering it to know that, either.

Answer (score 0):

if your datagridview has no checkboxes or custom-made columns, you can just check at every step if all your fields from your last row are not null or empty, then make the AllowUserToAddRows = true

example:

```
bool all_fields_completed=true;
for(int i=0;i<mydatagrid.Columns.count;i++)
if(String.IsNullorEmpty(mydatagrid.Rows[mydatagrid.Rows.Count-1].Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
   all_fields_completed=false;

if (all_fields_completed==true) mydatagrid.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Click on your Datagridview --> Click Datagridview task --> and Check Enable Adding.

Regards

Comment: if I do this the user can't add new rows at any time.