# Force datagridview call row validating after finish input

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, .net-2.0, datagridviewrow

I'm creating a `Form` with a `Bound Datagridview` inside it. On `Form_Load` or `Row_Validating`, I added new row to `Datagridview` by:

```
Private Sub PurchaseInRowAdd()
        'add new row to datagridview
        Dim dtRow As DataRow = CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.DataSource, DataTable).NewRow()
        dtRow.Item("InvoiceID") = 0
        dtRow.Item("KindID") = CType(CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Columns("colPurchaseKind"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource, DataTable).Rows(0)("KindID")
        dtRow.Item("InvoiceSign") = ""
        dtRow.Item("InvoiceNo") = ""
        dtRow.Item("InvoiceDate") = New Date(objController.ProcessYear, objController.ProcessMonth, 1)
        dtRow.Item("ID") = CType(CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Columns("colPurchaseCustomer"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource, DataTable).Rows(0)("ID")
        dtRow.Item("Product") = ""
        dtRow.Item("Price") = "0.00"
        dtRow.Item("Note") = ""
        dtRow.Item("Tax") = CType(CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Columns("colPurchaseKind"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource, DataTable).Rows(0)("Tax")
        dtRow.Item("TaxCode") = CType(CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Columns("colPurchaseCustomer"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource, DataTable).Rows(0)("TaxCode")
        dtRow.Item("VAT") = ""

        CType(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Add(dtRow)
    End Sub
```

The problem here is, when user finished input in that new row and press enter, `Row_Validating` hasn't been fired because there's no row below it. So how can I force `Row_Validating` trigger when user finished input and press enter?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126523/how-to-add-new-row-to-datagridview-only-after-specific-cells-of-the-row-above-ar) solution, but it doesn't suit my case because I don't want to set `Enable Adding` to `True`. I want to handle row adding by code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I subclassed `DataGridView` and override `ProcessDialogKey` like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if(keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                KeyEnterPress(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
```

(I wrote this subclass in C#)

Then handle key enter press in my form like this

```
Private Sub PurchaseInCellKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Me.dgvPurchaseIn.CurrentRow.Index = Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            If PurchaseInRowValidate(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.CurrentRow.Index, True) Then
                Me.PurchaseInRowAdd()
                Me.deselectPurchaseCell(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.CurrentRow.Index)
                Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Rows(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("colPurchaseSign").Selected = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

This line:

```
Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Rows(Me.dgvPurchaseIn.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("colPurchaseSign").Selected = True
```

will trigger row validating