# How To validate Correct Dates In DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two columns From Date and To Date, i want to prevent User to select new row until user put correct Date, currently the method i am using It is Just allowing user to select new either the date selection is wrong.

```
private void metroGrid1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
            {
                DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;
                DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["fromDate"].Value);
                DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["toDate"].Value);

                if (fromDate > toDate)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("From Date Must be less than To Date");
                }

            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by selecting a new row, did you meant inserting a new row?

Comment: i want to stop user on current row until he select correct date.... the thing is happening Right now as i select wrong date. it generates the Error ""From Date Must be less than To Date" and then new row automattically generates and let him enter values on a new row row.

Comment: I think you should look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126523/how-to-add-new-row-to-datagridview-only-after-specific-cells-of-the-row-above-ar

Comment: thanks @Arman.Salehi it worked for me